# Subset of regular languages

Tags: automata, regular-language

Assume $L_1$ and $L_2$ two regular languages, and $L_1\subseteq L\subseteq L_2$. Does this imply that $L$ is a regular language?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L_1=\emptyset$, $L_2=\Sigma^*$. I think not.

Comment: To add on a small bit, let $L = \{ 0^{n} 1^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \}$, the canonical non-regular, context-free grammar. We know that in this case, $L$ is not regular by the pumping lemma.